# How to use select2 in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to use "select2" in angular 6 for autocomplete. Who's ever use it before? , help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng2-select2`

[Angular wrapper for Select2 (ng2-select2)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select2)

Comment: Its not working with Angular v6. Even most basic example with demo data is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways with the help of **`JQuery`**

1. [Select2 docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control):

We can do this like below select2 official library methods

```
...

ngAfterViewInit(){
   $('.select2').on('select2:select', (event) => {
       // code you want to execute when you hit select2 combo  
   });
}

...
```

2. Using `Id` of **`select`** tag

Here we are using the Id of select in Life cycle method of `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
<select select2 style="width:100%;" class="select2" id="symbolId" [(ngModel)]="selectedContractDetails.name">
     <option *ngFor="let symbol of service.symbols" value="{{symbol}}">{{symbol}}</option>
</select>
```

In **TS file:** try to do some changes like below in  **`ngAfterViewInit()`**

```
... 

ngAfterViewInit(){
   $('#symbolId').on('change', (event) => {
       var symbolSelected= event.target.value;
       //you can use the selected value
   });
}

...
```

> **P.S:** Though it's not recommended to use JQuery in Angular, for Select2 library it's the only way make it work.

Comment: we need to implement in typescript only

Comment: @perumalN can you elaborate your comment please... :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else landed here. There are lots of forks of angular wrappers for Select2 but they all sizeable and also require both JQuery (1.32MB) and Select2 (839kB).

If you are interested in a simplified clone of Select2 in pure angular without any dependencies you could try this one:

https://github.com/timbophillips/angular-components-workspace/tree/master/projects/filtered-select

https://www.npmjs.com/package/filtered-select

Far fewer bells and whistles but for my purposes I really just want the searchable select control.

Install it as an npm module (16.2kB) or use the source code. Its compiled without Ivy so it should work on old and new angular projects.

Comment: filtered-select feels like it's still work in progress. It's very simple compared to Select2, which is fine for many cases but the demo available still looks and feels unfinished.

Comment: Does anyone knows how to set selected value after loading the component?

Answer (score 0):

1.If you are using bootstrap then use typeahead feature of bootstrap

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

2.If material then use autocomplete

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Comment: did it help you ?

Comment: I have used the typeahead feature

Answer (score 0):

1. import js and css of select2 plugin
2. create a directive

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var $;
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelect2]'
})
export class Select2Directive implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.element.nativeElement.focus();
    $(this.element.nativeElement).select2();
    $(this.element.nativeElement).select2({
      theme: 'bootstrap4'
    });
  }
}
```

3. use

```
<select appSelect2 class="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;">
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Alaska</option>
    <option>California</option>
    <option>Delaware</option>
    <option>Tennessee</option>
    <option>Texas</option>
    <option>Washington</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried the above steps and getting this error----Error: src/app/select2.directive.ts:11:35 - error TS2551: Property 'select2' does not exist on 
type 'JQuery<any>'. Did you mean 'select'?

11     $(this.element.nativeElement).select2();