# unable to get value select2 multiple select in Reactive Forms angular 6

Tags: angular6, jquery-select2, multiple-select

Alabama
                Alaska
                California
                Delaware
                Tennessee
                Texas
                Washington

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you want to achieve and perhaps show some code you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear yet,but i have done this kind of requirement before

check this answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52849229/9764133

> you can do this with JQuery by adding an Id to select tag

```
<select select2 style="width:100%;" class="select2" id="symbolId" [(ngModel)]="selectedContractDetails.name">
        <option *ngFor="let symbol of service.symbols" value="{{symbol}}">{{symbol}}</option>
    </select>
```

In your **ngAfterViewInit()**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   $('#symbolId').on('change', (event) => {
       var symbolSelected= event.target.value;
       //you can use the selected value
   });
}
```